# How to import python package with two files with 'from ... import ...' statement

Tags: python-3.x, import, package, python-module

My **directiory** looks like this:

```
test.py
foo/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

**bar** is a python class and looks like this:

```
class Bar:
...
```

**foo** is just a script and looks like this:

```
from foo.bar import Bar
def fun1():
...
```

**init**

Now in **test.py** I want to import the package and access **fun1()** as follows:

```
from foo import foo
fun1()
```

However this fails. I can only call **fun1()** like this:

```
foo.fun1()
```

I have read dozens of posts and articles regarding python packages/modules/imports whatsoever but I just can't seem to figure out what I'm supposed to to... :/

I would be glad for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put in your **__init__.py** file

```
from .foo import fun1
```

and in **test.py** you can do:

```
from foo import fun1

...
fun1()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right, you can try:

```
from foo import foo as f
import f.fun1()
```

then you can call it as

```
fun1()
```